# when using remapColumns in different event, sort icon doesn't show when clicking a header

Tags: jqgrid

I saved my column permutation info into a table. This information can be reloaded in beforeRequest event:

```
mynewperm = {....};

myGrid.jqGrid("remapColumns", mynewperm, true);
```

The columns are reordered correctly. However I lost the header icon. Now if I click any column header, I  can not see 
the sort icon anymore, then can not sort any column. How can I get it back?

Thank you,

yh

Comment: Have you tried setting `updateCells` to false - `myGrid.jqGrid("remapColumns", mynewperm, false);`? Otherwise, it might help if you could post a larger code example or even a jsfiddle.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work. The code is in:                          beforeRequest:function(){                                             ................                                               perm =processPermStr(permst);if(perm){                                                 myGrid.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm,  true);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed if you look at the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` source, the line is:

```
var previousSelectedTh = ts.grid.headers[ts.p.lastsort].el, newSelectedTh = ts.grid.headers[idxcol].el;
```

Line #1982 in my version.  I fixed it by modifying the file and added this just before that line:

```
        if (ts.p.lastsort < 0)  // johnl.
            ts.p.lastsort = 0;
```

The problem was that `ts.p.lastsort` was -1.

Answer (score 2):

if you are able to change the code, you could test for an undefined of a.grid.headers[a.p.lastsort].

In the source file it could look like this:

```
// old 
var previousSelectedTh = ts.grid.headers[ts.p.lastsort].el

// new:
var previousSelectedTh = ts.grid.headers[ts.p.lastsort] ? ts.grid.headers[ts.p.lastsort].el : null
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just managed to fix this issue myself but not using the methods described above.  I was receiving the following error message when trying to sort columns in a jqgrid:

```
TypeError: a.grid.headers[a.p.lastsort] is undefined js/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js?1.4:86
```

I should note that it was Firebug that produced this error message.  Our company develops web applications for Chrome but Chrome's Javascript console produced a very uninformative error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
```

After stripping out all but the jqGrid declaration on the page causing the issue, it transpired that removing the "multiSelect" option declaration for the jqGrid solved the issue.  Apparently, declaring this option causes an additional hidden column to be added into the grid rendered which enables users to select multiple grid rows at a time.  I'm not exactly sure *why* this caused an issue but after consultation with the programming director here our best guess is that there is a for loop somewhere in the jqGrid library code which is called when column sorting is applied and the loop is not taking into account this extra column which results in it not being defined.

Strange answer to a strange issue but hopefully this will help somebody out in future and save them around 3 hours of debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue :

It append to me since i apply the "remapColumns" method in the "loadComplete" event (i get back user column configuration from a cookie).

So when I try to sort a column nothing happen. I got this error in firebug :

a.grid.headers[a.p.lastsort] is undefined -> jquery.jqGrid.min.js (line 93)

maybe it will be helpful to find what the problem is

Thank you